# Setting up one configuration file for CodeIgniter

Tags: configuration, codeigniter

I'm building an app with CodeIgniter. My question is how do you combine the database config with a site wide config file? I want to have the config file based outside the application directory so that users will only need to modify one file without digging around inside the application directory.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a standard php `include()` to have the global config included within any one of the application's config files.